# How to access value returned by an event emitter in angular

Tags: angular, output, angular-test

Like I have a method -

I call this method from my unit test using value -

```
var eventValue = <ManagedColumns>{
      selectedColumns : ["Select","Last Name"],
      availableColumns: ["First Name"]
    };

component.updateColumns(eventValue);
```

And method in the component is -

```
updateColumns(eventValue: ManagedColumns) {
    console.log("KKKKKKK"+JSON.stringify(eventValue));
    this.applyColumnChanges.emit(eventValue);
    console.log("LLLLLL"+JSON.stringify(this.applyColumnChanges));
  }
```

I want to assert that the event emitted in this method returns the same value as passed to it. When I try to (in test) -

```
console.log("MMMMMMMM"+JSON.stringify(component.applyColumnChanges));
```

It gives me something like below but not the value returned/emiited by emitter -

```
LOG: 'MMMMMMMM{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using  `this.applyColumnChanges` in the `console.log("LLLLLL"+JSON.stringify(this.applyColumnChanges));` 
which is the emitter not the emitted value. If you want to check the value just subscribe it like

```
this.applyColumnChanges.subscribe((emittedVal) => {
  console.log('This is emitted value'+ emittedVal);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything for me...not even the string 'This is emitted value'

Comment: you have to `subscribe` before emitting. Write above lines somewhere in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit` or anywhere but before this line `this.applyColumnChanges.emit(eventValue);`

Comment: Awesome. And what `subscribie` before change here btw? Thanks a bunch.